# How can I add a state to my online taskboard TFS(Team Foundation Server)

Tags: tfs, projects-and-solutions

I want to add a state to my taskbaord in online Team Foundation Server project. 
I can't figure out how to do that. See pic.

[image]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible to add a State to the Task board. You can only do this on the Kanban boards.